# Should the gogs suggested ssh url be the real on disk location of the repository?

Tags: gogs

I'm having trouble with the gogs ssh url,but am not sure if the web ui config needs corrected, or whether server config needs changed.

The recommended ssh url in the web ui always has the same user and looks like this:

```
gogs@myserver.com:org/application.git
```

**The problem:** That url is not the user's name, nor the complete location on disk of the repository. Is that normal? Replacing the user gets authenticated, but the location is denied.

```
//no go,  does not appear to be a git repository
git clone ssh://myUserName@myserver.com:org/application.git
```

**My current workaround:** The repositories are kept on disk at /gogs-repositories, and I can clone them by going directly to them:

```
git clone ssh://myUserName@myserver.com:/gogs-repositories/org/application.git
```

But this modification has drawbacks. There are write permission/collaboration issues that have to be managed through CLI instead of through gogs.

**Update:**

Fiddling with it, I did get the suggested link to pass initial authenticaton, but debugging shows a gogs specific error

```
Gogs: "Invalid key ID".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually pretty common, notice that GitHub, GitLab etc actually use `git@server` regardless of username, the user is identified through the public key instead. The path doesn't use the real physical path because the git server (in this case, gogs) handles everything.

If you haven't been able to clone using the `gogs` username, you likely haven't set up authentication correctly, browse to `yourserver.com/user/settings/ssh` and paste your public key there. If you haven't done so already, just run `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` in your terminal, leave the directory at its default value unless you have configured a custom location, and paste the content of `id_ed25519.pub`.

Comment: ok, well now If i debug git clone from client side,  the server response includes  "Gogs: Internal error". nothing in the gogs.log though.

Comment: answered the question. Fiddling with it, I got the ssh part to authenticate, but the error I get is "Gogs: Invalid key ID".